# count of non-empty subsequences with integer average

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Is there any algorithm to count number of non_empty sub sequence of an array with integer average, expect the brute force way? Any dp solution?

for example for {2, 6, 2}
we have 6 sub squences with integer average.

1. 2
2. 6
3. 2
4. 2 6
5. 6 2
6. 2 2

I tried brute force approach but I want better algorithm using DP.

Comment: Wouldn't 1) and 3) above be the same sequence and only count once? And wouldn't `(2, 6, 2)` also be a subsequence?

Comment: What about the empty sequence.?

Comment: I think OP is looking to count all subsequences, where only subsequences with the same indices are considered equivalent and not to be double-counted, whose average is integral. So 1) and 3) would be different because they likely refer to different indices in the array, while `(2, 6, 2)` is not allowed because its average is `10/3`, which isn't an integer. There's a cubic solution but it's not clear from the original post if that will meet the intended constraints.

Comment: Do you only need the count or also the  sub squences ?

Comment: @wLui155 Your cubic solution can easily be turned into a quadratic solution by first filling a prefix-sum array ;-)

Comment: @Ceenaa Can you describe the "bruteforce solution" that you tried?

Comment: @MrSmith42 I just want the count

Comment: @wLui155 yes Im looking for what you said.

Comment: @Stef could you please explain the solution or write down the C++ code for it

Comment: @Stef subsequences can be non-contiguous, so I don't think your prefix sum idea works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a straightforward `O(n^4)` algorithm.

```
def integer_average_subsequences (items):
    answer = 0
    for l in range(1, len(items)+1):
        counts = [[0] * l for _ in range(l+1)]
        counts[0][0] = 1
        for item in items:
            for j in range(l, 0, -1):
                for k in range(l):
                    counts[j][(k + item) % l] += counts[j-1][k]
        answer += counts[l][0]
    return answer
```

It may seem wasteful to redo the DP for each length. But if there are more than `O(n^2)` sums, it is actually faster to do it this way.